# Java Regular expression for string match that should contain only alphanumeric and "-"

Tags: java, regex

I need to add the regular expression in java to test the string whether it contains only alphanumeric( with or without "-").
Ex:

```
ADB123
ABC-D1
12ABCD
A-BCD1
```

etc.

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Why the avalanche of downvotes and close votes? What is "vague, ambiguous, incomplete or overly broad" in this question? To me, it's extremely clear, unambiguous and clearly scoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
for (String s : "ADB123,ABC-D1,12ABCD,A-BCD1,abcd12,a.b.c,12£".split(",")) {
    boolean ok = s.matches("[-\\p{Alnum}]+");
    System.out.println(s + " is ok: " + ok);
}
```

prints

```
ADB123 is ok: true
ABC-D1 is ok: true
12ABCD is ok: true
A-BCD1 is ok: true
abcd12 is ok: true
a.b.c is ok: false
12£ is ok: false
```

The regex `[-\\p{Alnum}]+` means

- `[ ]+` means one or more of any of the characters.
- `-` at the start means `-` not and not something else.
- `\\` in a String literal turns into just `\` as it is an escape character.
- `\p{Alnum}` is a predefined list of alpha and numeric characters.

See the documentation for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more details.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Thanks it is working fine.Can you explain me how it works i am poor in regular expressions

Comment: This is the best answer because it uses the alnum class rather than a range.

Comment: @RamCh Gave a breakdown of what the regular expression means.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, Thanks now i got it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression out:

```
/^[A-Z0-9-]*$/
```

You can run it like this:

```
str.matches("[A-Z0-9-]*"); // Returns a Boolean
```

Comment: Does the above regex cater lower case alphabets?

Comment: The `^` and `$` are redundant for `matches()`

Answer (score 2):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
"^[A-Z0-9-]+$"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape that `-`.

Comment: You are right: the minus indicates a range in a character class (when it is not at the first position after the "[" opening bracket or the last position before the "]" closing bracket.
    Example: "[A-Z]" matches any uppercase character.
    Example: "[A-Z-]" or "[-A-Z]" match any uppercase character or "-".

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
"^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$"
```

Comment: If you are trying to escape `-` using `/` which should be \ then you don't need that. And why you have both : - `*{0,}`. Using `*` itself means `0 or more`/

Comment: Ranges are risky - you can't be 100% sure what you are including or leaving out, because you don't know what the current charset includes between the first and last characters.  In most charsets, your range excludes accented letters; did you mean to do that?  Did you consider it?

Comment: **^[[:alnum:]-]+$** would be safer than a range.

Comment: But this can also be consider as a solution